# Sql Server select datetime without seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have datetime column value below

```
2015-01-04 20:37:00.000
```

I tried below

```
cast(cast(MyDateColumn as date) as datetime)+cast(datepart(hour,MyDateColumn ) as float)/24
as MyDateColumn
```

and

```
CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16),MyDateColumn,113) AS datetime) as MyDateColumn
```

These are did not work for me

How can i get above datetime as **01-04.2015 20:37** ?

Comment: A `DATETIME` has seconds and fractional seconds, they may have a `0` value but they are still there. You can choose to convert it to a `string`/(`n`)(`var`)`char` where those portions are not displayed but this is a presentation issue. Still, a `DATETIME` has seconds and fractional seconds.

Comment: thanks for answer if you can write a code example i can accept best answer if it ups to me thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server this will work:

```
DECLARE @now [datetime]; 
SET @now = GETDATE();
SELECT
    CONVERT([varchar](10), @now, 105) + ' ' + 
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT([varchar](2), DATEPART(HOUR, @now)), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT([varchar](2), DATEPART(MINUTE, @now)), 2);
```

Comment: but we have to use specify variable @now repeatedly

Comment: @SonerSevinc this answer formats the date part as **`01-04-2005`**, different to what the question requests, is the question wrong?

Comment: You don't have to specify a variable. You can use any field name withing the SELECT statement instead. The format I used is the Italian format. If you prefer months-date, use 110 instead of 105 in the first convert.

Answer (score 42):

Since MS SQL 2012, you can use [`FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213505.aspx),

```
SELECT FORMAT([MyDateColumn], 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm')
```

Comment: Good catch! Convert will do the same.

Comment: @MaciejLos no it wont. CONVERT only covers a very limited set of formats

Comment: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'

Comment: @realPro, that looks like a sensible format to me but, its not the format that would answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

In MYSQL it will work

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS formated_date FROM table;
```

In MS SQL It will work

```
 SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm')
```

Comment: thanks for answer can you hafve any idea about ms sql according to your codE ?

Comment: @SonerSevinc, if you'd like an MS SQL answer you should tag the question accordingly.

Comment: stackoverflow does not let me enter it

Comment: @SonerSevinc It does, just type `sql-server`

Comment: SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm') 
case matters as the ms sql answer will put minutes where you expect month

Comment: `SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')` the uppercase `MM` is important, as @Thronk mentions.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server this should do the trick:

```
declare @dt datetime = '2015-01-04 20:37:00.000'

select right('0' + cast(DATEPART(MM, @dt) as varchar), 2) + '-' 
        + right('0' +cast(DATEPART(DAY, @dt) as varchar), 2) + '.'
        + cast(DATEPART(YEAR, @dt) as varchar) + ' '
        + right('0' +cast(DATEPART(HOUR, @dt) as varchar), 2) + ':'
        + right('0' +cast(DATEPART(MINUTE, @dt) as varchar), 2)
```

Comment: it is working however it removes 0 before 4 or before 1

Comment: Why to force the doors wide open? Use CONVERT instead. There is only one requirement: pass 3. parameter. Please, see my answer.

Comment: Nobody forces any doors. CONVERT can't produce this format.

Comment: @SonerSevinc, I updated the answer to also consider the leading zeros. Now these are included in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 100) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way and you get a datetime in return.

```
SELECT DATEADD(
  MILLISECOND,
  DATEPART(MILLISECOND, '2016-02-16 13:45:24.573') * -1,
  DATEADD(SECOND, DATEPART(SECOND,'2016-02-16 13:45:24.573') * -1,
  '2016-02-16 13:45:24.573')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the way i do it. I needed to get -2 minutes

```
select CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(CHAR(18),  DATEADD(minute, -2, getdate()) , 113) + '00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Format(Cast(Convert(varchar(15),Cast(timeval as Time),100) as DateTime),'hh:mm tt') As newtime
```

This will remove seconds from time as well as add AM,PM with time.