# Check Only date, hours & minute in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have date in database like `2019-05-02 12:14:20` and field name is `created_date` Now i want to get record with created date like `2019-05-02 12:14`. Don't want to check seconds.

I've tried with separating time but it won't work could you please suggest some solution which we can achieve in single mysql query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918193/sql-server-select-datetime-without-seconds

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to check a specific part of datetime to a string:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = '2019-05-02 12:14'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94c34120362431afba91b034c9d811ca)