# How do I format my date in a SQL query, namely to remove seconds?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1 has a date column in the following format:
`2021-05-01 03:00:00`

Table 2 has a date columns in this format:
`2021-05-01 03:00.0000000` (edited from 2021-05-01 03:00:00)

How can I show the date in Table 2 to be like the date in Table 1?

I search here and elsewhere and I found links like the following:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/
[Sql Server select datetime without seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918193/sql-server-select-datetime-without-seconds)

but I'm still having difficulty with my code:

`SELECT FORMAT(MAX(date1), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm') FROM table2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) are the columns?

Comment: perhaps typo, but use caps for month ...  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm

Comment: @Schwern datetime

Comment: @IamWarmduscher If they're both `datetime` they should both have the same format. Double check, please. Is one perhaps `datetime2`?

Comment: @IamWarmduscher Are you sure it isn't `2021-05-01 03:00:00.000000`? Note the `.` for microseconds.

Comment: @Schwern You are correct, It is with the `.` and not the `:`

Comment: @IamWarmduscher And the data types? Perhaps table1 is `smalldatetime` and table2 is `datetime2`?

Comment: If you're working with 1 > a few hundred rows `format()` is ok but note it's *much* slower than `convert` so the latter is always better to use with larger result sets.

Comment: @Schwern Its showing `datetime2` is the DATA_TYPE

Comment: To be precise, `datetime` and `date` datatypes don't have a display format, they are stored in a binary format. SSMS will use a default format when you query, but the actual formatting is really a job for your front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the `format` docs for dates and times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and the [date and time data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), we see `mm` is minutes and `MM` is months.

```
SELECT FORMAT(MAX(date1), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') FROM table2
```

It might be faster to [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles), but that also means using obscure convert codes.

```
select convert(datetime2, max(date1), 20);
```

---

The different formats suggest table1 is a `smalldatetime` and table2 is a `datetime2`. If you have to do this conversion a lot, consider making your datetime columns all the same type.

```
create table test (
  col_smalldatetime smalldatetime,
  col_datetime datetime,
  col_datetime2 datetime2
);

insert into test values ('2022-01-02 03:04:05', '2022-01-02 03:04:05', '2022-01-02 03:04:05');

select * from test;

col_smalldatetime   col_datetime                col_datetime2
2022-01-02 03:04    2022-01-02 03:04:05.000     2022-01-02 03:04:05.0000000
```

[Demonstration of different datetime types](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9825ec66916504a2906ffde6e9b2ad0f).

Comment: I can't explain why but convert() isn't working for me. Only format() is.

Comment: @IamWarmduscher How is it not working?

Comment: I can't really copy+paste. I can only take a pic with my phone since it's on my work computer. But, the date is formatted correctly with the FORMAT() function but not with CONVERT(). There could be another issue, namely that I'm running the query in Jupyter Notebook via pyodbc. But I'm not certain.

Comment: @IamWarmduscher thats why you need to create a [mre] using something we can access e.g. DBFiddle.

Comment: @Dale K If I could do so with my work computer, I would.